# How to get these input values in an HTML table using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the other input values, but they're always blank. Here's the code I got:

```
function savePo() {
  let table = document.getElementById("dtable");
  let [, ...tr] = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  let tableData = [...tr].map(r => {
    let td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
    return [...td].map((c, j) => j == 9 ? c.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked : j === 8 ? c.innerText : c.querySelectorAll('input').value)
  });
  console.log('Table Data: ' + tableData);
}
```

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/1ghryfz9/39/#&togetherjs=C4Vy6oHp2f) in case you feel like putting a finger on the issue.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which doesn't have a `value` property. Try mapping over it. `[...c.querySelectorAll('input')].map(({ value }) => value)`

Comment: What, exactly, are "the other" input values? Exactly what is "blank"? Exactly what are the expected/desired results, and what are the actual?

Comment: Note that adding a link to a live example *in addition* to having code in the question is welcomed, that shouldn't take the place of having [minimal sample code](http://sscce.org/) in the question itself, both so the question is self-contained and in case the linked page goes down, goes away or gets edited. For HTML, CSS an JS, the [Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/90527) feature allows you to create a [live example](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/90527) on SO itself.

Comment: Hey, @outis! Thank you! I usually post question on other subjects and still didn't quite know how to post it so that it can be run in the question itself. Thanks for the link with the live example instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not selecting the first input for cells that contain a regular text input (default case).

```js
return [...td].map((c, j) =>
  j == 9
    ? c.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked
    : j === 8
      ? c.innerText
      : c.querySelector('input').value) // <-- Only select the first input of the TD
```

---

Here is a working example.

**Note:** I would avoid the nested ternary. A switch-statement would work better and its easier to read.

```js
const findAll = (selector, element = document) =>
  [...element.querySelectorAll(selector)]

const extractData = (table) => {
  const header = findAll('thead tr th', table).map(th => th.textContent);
  const rows = findAll('tbody tr', table).map(tr =>
    findAll('td', tr).map((td, i) => {
      switch (i) {
        case 8:
          return td.textContent;
        case 9:
          return findAll('input[type="checkbox"]', td)[0].checked;
        default:
          return td.querySelector('input').value;
      }
    }));
   return { header, rows };
};

function savePo() {
  const table = document.querySelector('#dtable');
  const { header, rows } = extractData(table);
  const records = rows.map(row =>
    header.reduce((acc, col, idx) =>
      ({ ...acc, [col]: row[idx] }), {}));
  
  console.table(records);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:18%">Tela</th>
      <th style="width:15%">Color</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Pantone</th>
      <th style="width:15%">Contenido</th>
      <th style="width:7%">Acho(m)</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Peso(gsm)</th>
      <th style="width:7%">Precio/m (COP)</th>
      <th style="width:8%">Metros (m)</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Precio Total sin IVA</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Sel.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="fdfdfdfd"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="fsfdsfsfd"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="100cot"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="1.63"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="273"></td>
      <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="178" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="ererewr"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="vcbchbdgfh"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1f23dfdsn"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="267"></td>
      <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="176" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onClick=savePo()>
  Save PO
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! All new to me and I'll have to learn this other approach. Very insightful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update your return statement like below

```
return [...td].map((c, j) => { j == 9 ? (c.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked) : j == 8 ? c.innerText : c.querySelector('input').value } )
```